# Change Direction of Animation

Tags: animation, armature, unity

I have a walk animation from Mixamo on my rig (and many more) but I need to retarget the direction the animation walks.

***What doesn't work***
Currently when i try using the root bone or a rotation constraint among others the rotation is rotated but the motion is still along the Y axis and other smaller movements aren't rotated.

***What I want to achieve***
Rotate the rig with it's animations around the Z axis and have the animations adjust to this change.
eg: Rig walks forward along Y axis I rotate the rig by 90deg on the Z axis so that it walks along the X axis.

I'm wanting this as I want to use blend trees for motion in Unity3D and spent a few days on this and no closer to a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate the armature and rotate it (the whole object) as you want. Then select the root bone of the original one and add a Copy Transforms constraint to it. Select the new armature's root bone as target, then select Pose>>Animation>>Bake Action, check in all option and click on Ok.

Comment: Thanks, Iv'e been running some tests today and got it working!, If you put it as the answer I will accept it, again much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this in my own project by creating an empty setting its x and y to the same as the root bone in the armature, then selecting the root bone and creating object constraints for rotation location and scale all linked to the empty. Make sure to set these to after original where possible. Then you can move, rotate, scale your empty and the changes will be applied to the armature while still keeping the same animation.